# VSC check in project relevant extensions to a version control system

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created a project (in my case flutter) with Visual Studio Code. Therefore I installed some extensions. It is planned to upload the project to gitlab.

My problem relates to the extension: Is it possible to store all extensions used in the git repo as well so other developers don't have to install them all manually?

My first thought was about to reference these extension in the .vscode folder somehow, but I haven't found information on how this could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the required extensions to the Workspace Recommendation:

- Go to the extension bar: `Ctrl+Shift+X`
- Select an extension
- use context menu (right click) and select: **Add to Workspace Recommendation**

don't put the big extensions to the repo, you need to update these big files for each update and that will bloat the repo to an enormous size.

Comment: I did not expect it to be so easy, thank you!